# If $x^a<\ln(x)<x^b$, then how are $a$ and $b$ bounded?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, upper-lower-bounds

**Question:** Let $x^a<\ln(x)<x^b$, for sufficiently large $x$. How large can $a$, and how small can $b$ be, such that this inequality stays true?

**Context:** While reading about computational complexity, I found a lot of complexities expressed in terms of $\ln n$. But it's tricky to relate this to complexities such as $n^{1.2}$. So I tried to find a way of expressing $\ln(x)$ as $x^a$.

**Attempt:** Clearly $1<\ln(x)<\sqrt{x}$, so $x^0<\ln(x)<x^{0.5}$. Hence, the maximum possible value of $a$ is at least $0$, while $b$ has a minimum of at most $0.5$.

But can $a$ be made any larger or $b$ any smaller?

Comment: $a$ cannot be made any larger. $b$ can be made as small as you wish (but still larger than 0).

Comment: This is directly related to rates of growth between polynomials and exponential functions. Just replace $x$ with $\exp(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that

$$x-1\ge\ln(x)$$

Substituting $x=t^a$ gives us

$$t^a-1\ge a\ln(t)$$

Assuming $a>0$,

$$\frac{t^a-1}a\ge\ln(t)$$

and assuming $a<0$,

$$\frac{t^a-1}a\le\ln(t)$$

Combining both cases gives us

> $$\frac{1-t^{-a}}a\le\ln(t)\le\frac{t^a-1}a\quad\forall a>0$$

Comment: First inequality is the other way around: $x-1>\log x$, $x\ne1$.

Comment: Oh whoops, my bad!

Comment: Hi, @Simply, great answer - very tight bounds! But it's not *quite* what I was looking for, since I was asking about $t^a$, not $\frac{t^a-1}{a}$

Comment: @Jam You can probably infer from my answer, can't you?

Comment: And as far as O comparisons, the extra constants don't matter.

Comment: @Jam It is possible to infer about $t^a$ from this answer.  You have to make some use of the fact that these bounds hold for all $a>0$, not just one particular value.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Who said anything about O comparisons? :).  The constants in the OP are fixed, not implied.

Comment: Sorry, I inferred that myself. In any case, it should be relatively clear...